# Why C# OutOfMemory exception in System.Drawing.dll?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Let's simplify the model.

```
class Container
{
    //other members
    public byte[] PNG;
}

class Producer
{
    public byte[] Produce(byte[] ImageOutside)
    {
        using (MemoryStream bmpStream = new MemoryStream(ImageOutside), 
            pngStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(bmpStream);
            bitmap.Save(pngStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            pngStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            byte[] PNG = new byte[pngStream.Length];
            pngStream.Read(PNG, 0, (int)pngStream.Length);
            bitmap.Dispose();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            return PNG;
        }
    }
}
```

The main function keep making `Container container = new Container();` produce PNG for container.PNG, and `Queue.Enqueue(container)`
use using() clause doesn't work at all.

While this repeat for about 40+ times(it varies), it throws an exception. Sometime it's OutOfMemoryException and sometime It's something like "GDI+ normal error"(I am not sure how it is exactly in English, I just translated it).
But If I try and catch the exception and simply ignore it, it can still continue producing more but not unlimitedly though, just more forward. 
The occupied memory shown in task manager is only about 600 - 700 MB when the first exception is thrown and it finally stops at about 1.2GB. I have tried this:

```
while (true)
{
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(4500, 5000);
    list.Add(b);
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBox1.Text = list.Count.ToString(); });
}
```

It never throws any exception though 99% memory(about 11GB) has been allocated for the program, and all happen is the number in textBox1 no longer raise.

The way to avoid this may be not to produce so many things, but I still want to know the internal principle and reason and thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to dispose of each bitmap created. You are likely running out of graphic handles.

Comment: While(true) is an infinite loop that will keep running as fast as it can until you break. and the empty `using` with an empty Folder does nothing either.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `System.Drawing` classes have a bad habit of effectively doing "is it specific bad situation a? I'll throw this exception. Is it specific bad situation b? I'll throw that exception. For any other error condition, I'll guess that it's OutOfMemory" - i.e. it often throws this exception when the underlying problem is nothing to do with memory.

Comment: @Hans Passant I don't understand  since all I need is the byte[], I already dispose the bitmap before the stream dispose. Why the stream must remain readable? And what is underlying steam? There's no underline.

Comment: You keep adding large bitmaps to your list; this is most likely not about memory but about __'GDI handles'__. Watch them __in the task manager__ go up and up until your out of them..

Comment: @TaW http://wx1.sinaimg.cn/large/006FkGhagy1fd8s6wtrdfj30kx07raa6.jpg

Comment: Is any of those columns showing the GDI objects?? (You need to add the column to the display in TM)

Comment: @TaW Sorry about that because the header is not English. The GDI objects in the image is ONLY 150(When the exception is thrown and catch by vs in debug mode)

Comment: Ah, ok. Well that seems not to be the problem after all. The bad news is: This exception is thrwon for a lerge number of reasons, including funny pixel formats.... You will have to investigate further. Does it always happen at the same point? with the same images..?

Comment: @TaW To be a bit more specific, the producer are using bitmap(GDI+) as a tool to convert a byte[] to another byte[]. The Container is actually a mission, which has its own bitmap canvas as double-buffer to show the progress. It continue to redraw the canvus once it started. The convert function is complex and could not paste here but ALL exception I have seen is from this function and never in the double-buffer. This is wired because if the GDI+ is really out of memory, why the exception never happen in the canvus part or somewhere else. I have MANY threads drawing double-buffer canvus.

Comment: @TaW  I simply ignore the exception and it can go on now.

Comment: @TaW @ Damien_The_Unbeliever It's because of mixed platform

Comment: The platform target can affect the available memory.

Answer (score 0):

with `byte[] PNG = new byte[pngStream.Length];` you allocate a large portion of memory to store the image.

The follow call it's useless, you have already disposed the stream.

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

The memory used by PNG array cannot be released, because there is active reference in function return.

I suggest to return a stream instead of an array of bytes.

Otherwise after you call the method `Produce` remember to remove the reference to PNG before call again.

sample:

```
while (true)
{
    Byte[] b = new Byte[1000];
    b = this.Produce(b);
    //Use your array as you need, but you can't assign it to external property, otherwise memory cannot be released 
    b = null; //remove the reference, (in reality, in this example assign null is not necessary, because b will be overwritten at next loop.
    GC.Collect(); //Force garbage collector, probably not necessarry, but can be useful
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

The platform compilation can affect the maximum available memory:

- In a 32 bit application, you have a maximum of 2 GiB of available memory
- In a 64 bit application  you have 2 Tib of available memory, but
  single object (class) cannot exceed 2 Gib.
- In a UWP application there are other limitation in dependence of the
  device
- Any CPU is complied just in time, when you launch the application,
  and can be run both 32-bit and 64, it depends from machine architecture
  and system configuration.